# Breeze.js - is there something like visualizer to examine local entity cache?

Tags: breeze, javascript-debugger, debuggervisualizer

I am getting better with Chrome and Firefox debugging tools but I still have not found a way to easily examine the local entity cache managed by Breeze.  I can see the data coming over the wire easily but once I am working against the local cache I would like something like the visualizers in VS C# debugging to examine the local data, see added objects, changed objects and the shape of objects when I have extended the metadata.

I have Glimpse installed but that seems only good for the wire traffic.  I have an eval of Hibernating Rhinos EF profiler and will install that if there is something in there that will do the trick.

Surely somebody else has wanted this and figured out a visualizer or can just point to someplace in the Chrome or Firebug stuff that I am missing?

Comment: I don't know of any nifty tools, but it's not that hard to build something to spit the info out on a web page.  The [NorthBreeze sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/northbreeze) has a "scoreboard" on its home page.  It loops through all the changed entities and uses Angular to display the changes.  See the (crude) code for it [on github](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/NorthBreeze/NorthBreeze/App/views/home.html)